# Список возможных значений ключа -march для файла qmake.conf

Tags: c++, qt

Например есть файл qmake.conf для MCU iMX6 там значение -march=armv7-a,
а для MCU iMX287 рекомендуют -march=armv5te на что конфигуратор ругается

`Makefile:207: recipe for target 'arch.o' failed
make: *** [arch.o] Error 127
Unable to determine architecture!
Could not determine the target architecture!`

Собственно сабж, где посмотреть все возможные значения?

Comment: `gcc --target-help` там в числе прочего будет список доступных `march`'ей; вместо штатного `gcc`, само собой, нужно запускать версию из тулчейна, которым собираешься собирать проект...

Comment: вроде правильно распаковал, а результат такой `/opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++ --target-help
bash: /opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-g++: No such file or directory`

Comment: значит что-то неправильно... проверь пути и куда симлинки ведут...

Comment: уже не понимаю, как еще надо рапаковать тар, и почему в гуевом менеджере файлов все видно, а запускаться не хочет

Comment: здесь вряд ли что-то умное скажу... но `No such file or directory` говорит о какой-то глупой ошибке с твоей стороны (или экстроординарных обстоятельствах)... распаковать — элементарно: `tar xf <файл>`... ещё могут быть проблемы с путями/либами тулчейна, но это нужно будет решать после того, как файл отыщется...

Comment: если несложно, гляньте, в самом низу imx28 [ссылка](https://zao-zeo.ru/dokuwiki/doku.php/linux#imx28)

Comment: у меня сейчас интернет по талонам... так что в ближайшее время скачать не получится... может через пару дней гляну...

Comment: посмотрел — [УМВР](http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Ws9yJXKK2m/)... hello world с `-march=armv5te` тоже собирает... кьютового ничего собирать не пробовал, но не вижу причин (кроме того что компилятор относительно старый), почему это могло бы несработать...

Comment: Я неверно поставил вопрос полагая что виной  несуществующий ключ, а по факту у меня не работают исполняемые файлы из каталога компилятора. Был бы признателен за помощь и объяснения что не так с симлинками по ссылке

Comment: `a@ubuntu:/$ opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc --target-help
bash: opt/freescale/usr/local/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi/bin/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi-gcc: No such file or directory
`  на всякий случай создал новую виртуальную машину

Comment: архив точно послностью скачан? распаковался без ошибок?

Comment: да, уже не единожды, так делал, на всякий случай скачал тут `https://git.maselettronica.com/maselettronica/ltib_toolchain/tree/master/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0/arm-fsl-linux-gnueabi` распаковал в хоум, все так же

Comment: распаковываю так `tar -zxvf'/home/a/gcc-4.4.4-glibc-2.11.1-multilib-1.0.tar.gz' -C /`

Comment: сами файлы после этого на месте? распаковываешь от root'а? и уменя сколь-нибудь разумные идеи кончились...

Comment: все оказалось проще, я на 64х, `sudo apt-get install gcc-multilib и возможно sudo apt-get install gcc-6-multilib

sudo apt-get -f install sudo apt-get install zlib1g:i386`  и эту проблему я проскочил

Comment: ответьте на вопрос, ваш первый комментарий вполне подходит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Список доступных архитектур для опции `-march` можно посмотреть в `gcc --target-help`, типовой вывод будет содержать в том числе примерно такой список (для *x86*/*amd64*):

```
...
  -march=CPU[,+EXTENSION...]
                      generate code for CPU and EXTENSION, CPU is one of:
                       generic32, generic64, i386, i486, i586, i686,
                       pentium, pentiumpro, pentiumii, pentiumiii, pentium4,
                       prescott, nocona, core, core2, corei7, l1om, k1om,
                       iamcu, k6, k6_2, athlon, opteron, k8, amdfam10,
                       bdver1, bdver2, bdver3, bdver4, znver1, btver1,
                       btver2
                      EXTENSION is combination of:
                       8087, 287, 387, 687, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3,
                       sse4.1, sse4.2, sse4, avx, avx2, avx512f, avx512cd,
                       ...
...
```

Cамо собой, при использовании кросс-компилятора, нужно запускать версию `gcc` из тулчейна для целевой платформы.

---

Также список архитектурно-зависимых опций можно найти в [документации](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Submodel-Options.html#Submodel-Options) к `gcc`.